# ¿Cómo pasar él ID de un objeto en un evento click?

Tags: typescript, angular5

**Contexto**

Estoy tratando de obtener el valor del id de un objeto con un evento click, pero no parece estar funcionando. El objeto viene mediante un ngFor de la siguiente manera

```
<ngb-panel *ngFor="let diagnosticoFoda of diagnosticoFodas ;trackBy: trackId"  (click)="cargarElementosFoda(diagnosticoFoda.id)" >
```

Como ven es parte de un acordeón y la idea es que por cada diagnostico FODA me cree un nuevo panel dentro del acordeón y al momento de desplegarlo obtenga yo él id para cargar otros elementos vinculados a ese diagnostico.

del lado del TS tengo esto:

```
 cargarElementosFoda(id_foda){
        console.log(id_foda);
    }
```

**EL problema:**

Al momento de hacer el click estoy teniendo estos errores:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Mis preguntas:**
¿Cuál es la manera correcta de pasar el ID?

**Notas**
Soy nuevo en angular y TypeScript así que si me falto información agradecería me lo digna en los comentarios y actualizare la pregunta.

Comment: Qué es "trackId" en la parte: `trackBy: trackId`?

Comment: Hola me parece es una función para optimizar las actualizaciones de las colecciones de objetos mira https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dEIg-PR4Tew

Comment: En cualquier caso deberías tener definido (o conocer) "trackId", puesto que `trackBy:` recibe como parámetro una función o el nombre de una propiedad presente en "diagnosticoFoda" (que de hecho tendría que ser algo como `trackBy: diagnosticoFoda.trackId`). Haz una prueba retirando toda la parte del `trackBy:` de tu código o... por otro lado, verifica si tienes definido "trackId" que, reitero, debería ser una función para tratar la indexación de los elementos (que no estoy seguro que sea tu caso).

Comment: @DavidMork de hecho estoy considerando como alternativa usar el trackBy para poder obtener el id y ejecutar la función que trae los elementos de ese FODA si no encuentro la manera de hacer funcionar el evento click

Comment: El Id debería ser una propiedad del elemento `diagnosticoFoda`. La finalidad de usar el `trackBy` es, por un lado, permitir que se muestren correctamente elementos duplicados o idénticos en el `ngFor` haciendolo por el índice de cada elemento; sirve también para mejorar el rendimiento en la renderización de los elementos, diciéndole a angular que "rastree" la posición de cada uno por cierta propiedad en específico, por ejemplo el Id, o también el índice del elemento en la lista de elementos. Puedes obtener el índice agregando `; let i = index`, para el caso este se puede acceder desde `i`.